# Change maxlen attribute of collections.deque

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on a small project lately where the `maxlen` attribute of a `collections.deque` is set in accordance with a user-configurable parameter. State is stored between sessions; any active `deque` forms part of this state. There is therefore a need to change the `maxlen` attribute of each restored `deque` if there are configuration changes between sessions. At the moment, I am doing it like so:

```py
if current_setting != last_setting:
    # Deques are in a dictionary
    for k in dictionary:
        # Other data types and structures exist in this dictionary
        if dictionary[k].__class__() == deque():
            dictionary[k] = deque([*dictionary[k]], maxlen=current_setting)
```

Creating a new `deque` and unpacking the old one into it seems inefficient. My question is if there is either;

1. A way to change the value of the `maxlen` attribute of a `deque` after creation or, if this is impossible/ill-advised;
2. A more efficient way to do what is achieved in the example above?

Comment: as per the [doc of py 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque), `maxlen` is a read-only attribute. In that case, you have to create a new deque for every state change.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I suspect that, being a C module, what the docs say applies quite strongly here. Still, I live in hope that this is one of those cases where one can work a little wizardry via inheritance, even if certain caveats would apply.

Answer (score 0):

As [CKM's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658554/change-maxlen-attribute-of-collections-deque#comment109065519_61658554) tells, changing the `maxlen` is impossible since it is a read-only attribute.

```py
>>> d = deque("abcdefghij", maxlen=10)
>>> len(d)
10
>>> d
deque(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], maxlen=10)
>>> d.maxlen = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: attribute 'maxlen' of 'collections.deque' objects is not writable
```

In order to change the `maxlen`, you have to create a new `deque` object with the correct `maxlen` like this:

```py
>>> NEW_MAX_LENGTH = 3
>>> d = deque("abcdefghij", maxlen=10)
>>> d2 = deque(d, maxlen=NEW_MAX_LENGTH)
>>> d2
deque(['h', 'i', 'j'], maxlen=3)
```

See the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for more info.